# Tabpage not resizing on minimize/ maximimize

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have a windows form in my application with a tab control inside it. I have noticed that when I restore the application from the taskbar after minimizing it, the tabpage shrinks to half it's normal size and all controls inside move downwards. I have the tabpage docked to fill inside a TablePanelLayout. The tabs stay in place though. This does not happen upon resizing the form. Please help.

This is the relevant code from the designer.cs file

```
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.lookupTab);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage4);
        this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tabControl1.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 35);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 110);
        this.tabControl1.Multiline = true;
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1453, 601);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 39);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1445, 558);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "Settings";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // tabPage2
        // 
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 39);
        this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
        this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1445, 558);
        this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage2.Text = "Calibration";
        this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Comment: Can you add a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wth just the code needed to reproduce this

Comment: @stuartd added code from the designer.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. Posting it here in case someone else has the same problem. 
I set `this.tabControl1.Multiline = true;` to false and the problem disappeared.